# how to change system timezone using python in windows?

Tags: python, windows, timezone

How to change system timezone using python's win32api? I've tried using SetTimeZoneInformation.

```
win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation(year,
                            month,
                            dayofweek,
                            hour,
                            minute,
                            second,
                            milliseconds)
```

this gives me an error in milliseconds parameter.

```
TypeError: Objects of type 'int' can not be converted to Unicode.
```

What is the parameter for SetTimeZoneInformation? Documentation says that it needs privilege for SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME. How to set that in python? Using WMI?

thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on Tim Golden's [win32api docs](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__SetTimeZoneInformation_meth.html), the method takes a tuple of the following form:

[0] int : Bias

[1] string : StandardName

[2] SYSTEMTIME tuple : StandardDate

[3] int : StandardBias

[4] string : DaylightName

[5] SYSTEMTIME tuple : DaylightDate

[6] int : DaylightBias

More to the point, try `win32api.GetTimeZoneInformation` ([docs](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32api__GetTimeZoneInformation_meth.html)) to see what the tuple ought to look like so that `win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation` won't complain.

**Edit: Getting the necessary privilege**

You need the `SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME` privilege (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). There's a handy implementation of changing privileges, `AdjustPrivilege` [over here](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src%40m%40e%40medusa-0.5.4%40demo%40winFTPserver.py/42/win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges/python).

**Putting it all together:**

```
import ntsecuritycon, win32security, win32api

def AdjustPrivilege( priv ):
    flags = ntsecuritycon.TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | ntsecuritycon.TOKEN_QUERY
    htoken =  win32security.OpenProcessToken(win32api.GetCurrentProcess(), flags)
    id = win32security.LookupPrivilegeValue(None, priv)
    newPrivileges = [(id, ntsecuritycon.SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED)]
    win32security.AdjustTokenPrivileges(htoken, 0, newPrivileges)

# Enable the privilege
AdjustPrivilege(win32security.SE_TIME_ZONE_NAME)

# Set the timezone
win32api.SetTimeZoneInformation((-600,u'Eastern Standard Time',(2000,4,1,3,0,0,0,0),0,u'Eastern Daylight Time',(2000,10,1,2,0,0,0,0),-60))
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thank you @pandita, it works. Can I chage the current date and time with the second parameter? Because when I change the date/time using SetSystemTime, it will automatically add +8 hours or depending on the timezone.

Comment: @pandita If I wan to change the timezone into `Europe/London`, how can I do that? Simply replacing `Eastern Standard Time` won't work. Any explanation? Or, what are all the valid values for that argument?

Comment: @swdev I think the naming follows the standard timezone convention. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_zone_abbreviations). For London I'd try `Greenwich Mean Time`

Comment: The complete/exact timezone as defined in Windows 8.1 registry, is listed here : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749073(v=ws.10).aspx For London, I have to use `GMT Standard Time` Thanks @pandita!