# How Change Time zone my computer by using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I try change my computer time with python code, as in picture mentioned I want to **set time automatically** to set of then **change time zone**[image: please see the picture]

Comment: In general, you should not expect the operating system to allow you to do things like this (especially Windows, where users are mostly expected not to know much about computers at all, let alone programming). If it does, it's really a question about the operating system's API, rather than about writing code. You would have better luck on https://superuser.com.

Comment: Win32 API [SetTimeZoneInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/timezoneapi/nf-timezoneapi-settimezoneinformation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change system timezone using python in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20256946/how-to-change-system-timezone-using-python-in-windows)